# display html tags which has no attributes

Tags: python, regex

using regex I want to loop through a HTML content and then print out only HTML tags that have no attributes.

for example, if a html content is

```html
<h1>test</h1>
<h2>test2</h2>
<div id="content"></div>
<p>test3</p>
<div id="nav"></div>
<p>test3</p>
```

I want to loop through it and print the tags which have no attributes like this.

```html
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

At the moment i can print out all the html tags, i need some help to print out only the tags without the attributes.

```html
import re
file = open('file.html')
readtext = file.read()
lines = readtext.splitlines()
tags = re.findall(r'<[^>]+>',readtext)
for alltags in tags:
    print(alltags)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is generally not desirable to parse HTML content using regex, if you don't care about where any matching tag might be nested, we could try matching against the following regex pattern:

```
<\s*(\S+)\s*>.*?</\1>
```

This should match any HTML tags which have no attributes.  Here is a sample script:

```
input = """<h1>test</h1>
<h2>test2</h2>
<div id=\"content\"></div>
<p>test3</p>
<div id=\"nav\"></div>
<p>test3</p>"""
pattern = r'(<\s*(\S+)\s*>).*?(</\1>)'
for match in re.finditer(pattern, input):
    print(match.group(1) + match.group(3))
```

This prints:

```
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern being used:

```
<\s*(\S+)\s*>   match an HTML tag with no attributes, and also capture the tag name
.*?             then match any content, until reaching
</\1>           the matching closing tag (`\1` refers to the name of the opening tag)
```

Comment: Sorry, accidentally edited your answer then rolled it back. Time to sleep

Comment: @BradSolomon When my SO answer has a problem, I don't get mad.  I get _Brad_ `:-)`

Comment: Haha.  Can't claim I've never went straight to regex myself

Comment: thanks how to get rid of the tag contents? I just want the tags <h1></h1> <h2></h2><p></p><p></p> not the content

Answer (score 2):

[Think twice before parsing HTML with regex unless you have a good reason to.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/7954504)

Instead, consider a solution with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4.element import Tag

html = """\
<h1>test</h1> 
<h2>test2</h2> 
<div id="content"></div> 
<p>test3</p> 
<div id="nav"></div> 
<p>test3</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for t in soup.descendants:
    if isinstance(t, Tag) and not getattr(t, "attrs", None):
        print(f"<{t.name}></{t.name}>")
```

Result:

```
<html></html>
<body></body>
<h1></h1>
<h2></h2>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

(Note: BeautifulSoup will repair "broken" or incomplete by inferring the enclosing HTML and body tags for you; if you don't want that, it should be easy to filter them out with an initial `soup.find()`.)